# How does a flooding attack like "COORDINATOR9SUCKS9999999999" work?

Tags: spam-attack

How can it be a problem for IOTA if someone floods the network with zero value transactions? As far as I understand the promo, IOTA should work even better, the more transactions per second there are.

How does this attack work exactly?